# How do I prove that these propositions are equivalent by proving that these conditional statements are true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Propositions: p1, p2, p3, p4, and p5

Conditional Statements: p1 $\rightarrow$ p4, p3 $\rightarrow$ p1, p4 $\rightarrow$ p2, p2 $\rightarrow$ p5, and p5 $\rightarrow$ p3

Comment: Check that from any proposition comes out an arrow and arrive another one.

Comment: Check that you via the arrows can go from any proposition to any other.

Answer (score 0):

$p_1\implies p_4\implies p_2\implies p_5\implies p_3\implies p_1$

So the "circle is round": for every $i,j\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ we have $p_i\implies p_j$ (hence also $p_j\implies p_i$).